# Firebase app limit per project - getting to 1000

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have seen mentioned that there is actually a 1000 app hard limit to Firebase projects as it is the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs that have a limit of 30 and that these can be deleted if not needed.

I have removed the OAuth Client ID for my app from here https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
My app is a hybrid app (Ionic) and uses firebase auth with email/password via the web app not native one so it appears to work fine.

**I am assuming this means I am home free and can add up to 1000 apps if I manually delete the OAuth 2.0 Client ID each time?**

I am looking at adding Google and Facebook sign-in on the hybrid mobile apps using a native implementation (just for the google/fb auth) soon would this be something that I would need the native app OAuth 2.0 Client IDs for?  Is this just used for Google Auth?
If so I guess this would restrict me back to 30 apps but I could use the web Google Auth (although the UX is not as good).

I will also be using Firebase Cloud messaging if that is related at all.

I am not familiar with OAuth 2.0 Client IDs so any help is appreciated as I don't want to go down this route but find a problem later on once my product has gone to market.

Note: I have read the recommendations from Firebase that each tenant / customer / label should have its own project.  This is not how I want to implement my platform as the data is shared between tenants as users can belong to multiple tenants.  Plus making a project per tenant seems crazy if I have up to 1000 tenants.
Some of the tenants but not all will have their own branded app.  Same app with different branding and in different app store accounts.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#multi-tenancy

Comment: I haven't used Firebase with native iOS/Android yet. Do you really have to make a different app registration for each app deployment? I don't think that Firebase would validate the bundle ID. I think the only limitation with sharing app registrations would be FCM - you have to upload your APN to the app registration. You could consider using a different push notification provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the limit for apps has now been reduced to 30.
https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#apps-per-project

If you need more than 30, the above FAQ entry states:

> In the rare case your project requires more than 30 apps, you can request an app limit increase. Your project must be on the Blaze billing plan to make this request. Visit the Google Cloud Console to [make your request](https://console.cloud.google.com/admin/quotas?project=_) and have it evaluated.