# Copy a Firebase project

Tags: firebase

The Firebase recommendation for multi-tenancy or white labeling appears to be to create a separate project per customer/tenant.

Is there a way to easily clone or copy a Firebase project to avoid hours of setup and testing each time a customer is added?

Or a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy pretty much all the configuration/code that you might need from the firebase CLI:
Firestore Rules, Cloud Functions, Hosting, etc.

It's possible to create a script to build your application and deploy to several Firebase projects.

Personally, I would recommend using a single project for all of your clients though. If the Firestore rules are set up properly, it shouldn't be an issue to have multiple tenants on the same project.

Both routes definitely have their limitations though:
For multiple projects - there is a limit to how many projects you can tie to a single Google Billing account. If I remember correctly, the number is 5. That definitely complicates things if you want to scale to any reasonably large number.

For single projects - you can't have more than 20 Firebase Hosting domains on a single project. Presumably, you want to have either a subdomain or a custom domain for each client. Firebase does not have native support for this. You could try several things to solve for this, but it really depends on how your app handles white labeling.

I feel like managing dozens of Firebase projects would be really difficult to do. The single-project route will require a lot more work to set up initially, but I think it'll be easier to manage in the long run.

Comment: I completely agree regarding maintaining multiple projects.  I am fighting tooth and nail to avoid having to do this.  I have a datamodel and security that works perfectly on one project for multiple tenants.  The issue is for me is app limits per project as I have a mobile app.  See my post here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161846/10222449  They have just changed this from 1000 to 30 last week.  So I trying to gather as much information about the options available.

Comment: The [Firebase FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#projects-per-account) says that you can increase the quota for projects per billing account if your account is in good standing. By the way - I'm working on a project that will have similar white-labeling requirements. If you want to collaborate on a solution, feel free to email me. Contact info in profile.

Answer (score -1):

Firestore supports importing and exporting data. These operations are available in the cloud console as well as from `gcloud`.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

Comment: The question is about copying projects with the intention of white labeling. Presumably, you wouldn't need to copy one customer's Firestore data to another instance.

Comment: That depends, if the goal is to seed information to be used as a base to develop on top of, this may very well be what you want to do. Perhaps the individual asking the question can further clarify though.

Comment: Yeah it is more about the project and the configuration rather than the data.  I already have a script to seed the base firestore data. e.g. installing extensions (such as multiple big query exports), setup up multiple storage buckets, rules etc.  I am aware of how to script the rules and indexes but was wondering about all the other project parts and creating the project itself.

Comment: Scripting against `gcloud` or the firebase CLI may get you pretty far. It may be worth looking into terraform as well. Best of luck in solving your issue!